# Automatic creation of color-grading palette for UE

Tags: unreal-engine4

I'm trying to mimic colors of a real camera in the instance of `USceneCaptureComponent2D` using its postprocessing feature called "Color grading lookup table".

[The official manual](https://docs.unrealengine.com/4.27/en-US/RenderingAndGraphics/PostProcessEffects/UsingLUTs/) describes how to create the lookup table for that feature by manually adjusting an image and visually controlling how it looks.

I’ve got a pair of images of a photographic color grading palette (like one of [these](https://www.beyondthesight.com/film-colorists-needs/#elementor-toc__heading-anchor-0)).

One image was captured by a real photo camera, and another one comes from the scene capture component.

I’ve got the PDF file with that palette, and to get the latter image I’ve put it on a wall texture inside a UE level.

Is there any method to automatically create LUT?

My main issue is the color interpolation. Physical palettes contain about 20-50 colors, but the LUT includes 16x16x16 = 4096 colors.

Comment: I didn't find any "pair of images of a photographic color grading palette" on [the link](https://www.beyondthesight.com/film-colorists-needs/#elementor-toc__heading-anchor-0). You can convert a LUT to a PNG [here](https://greggman.github.io/LUT-to-PNG/), for example [these LUTs](https://www.rocketstock.com/free-after-effects-templates/35-free-luts-for-color-grading-videos/)

Comment: I create this pair manually. This file: https://www.datacolor.ru/media/products/2012-11-19/spydercheckr_reference_data.pdf was printed on a paper and converted to Uasset. Paper was captured by a real camera